# Should tag wlan be a synonym of wifi?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have the tag [wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) with nearly 900 questions.
We also have the tag [wlan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan) which has just 28 questions and no tag wiki.

On other sites, for example [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/tags/wireless-networking/synonyms), tags with these two names are synonymous.

Wouldn't it make sense to synonymise [wlan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan) to point to [wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi)?

Comment: Done!  Thanks for noticing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, technically wlan is a broader term than Wi-Fi which just happens to be a brand name... and, uhm well, describing the (by far) most widely adopted standard.

Interestingly Electronics.SE does not even have a [wlan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan). Unix&Linux does not synonymize [wlan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan) with [wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi) - though they have no tag definition for [wlan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wlan) either, use it only sparringly, and often double-tag with [wifi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wifi).

In practical terms, since everybody is using Wi-Fi as a general term for wlan anyways, we probably don't lose much in synonymizing those two tags.

Comment: Most of the 28 `wlan` questions were explicitly about wifi; many of them used both tags.  WRT to the others, I did not see anything that was explicitly about something that isn't wifi.